# UIImageView in NSArray

Tags: objective-c, uiimageview, nsarray

I have to cache some `UIImageView` inside an `NSMutableArray`, but when I go inside this array is always empty.

I use this code:

```
NSMutableArray *currentImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
UIImageView *imageV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 8, 50, 50)];
for (int i = 0; i< 20; i++) {
     imageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaut.png"];
     [currentImages addObject:imageV];
}
```

Can you help me?

Comment: You need to show more code. Where are you storing `currentImages`? Why are you storing image views in an array? Is this your real code?

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try something like this:

```
NSMutableArray *currentImages = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];

for (int i = 0; i< 20; i++) {
     UIImageView *imageV = [[UIImageView alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake(20, 8, 50, 50)];
     imageV.image = [UIImage imageNamed:@"defaut.png"];
     [currentImages addObject:imageV];
}
```

Not sure you need this though as it might slow your performance. I usually store `UIImage` names as `NSStrings` in an `NSArray` and then do whatever I want with them.

Answer (score 1):

You always add the same imageview, of which you changed the image, you should recreate the imageview inside your loop.

Depending on what you're trying to achieve it might be better to store the images and not the imageviews though, and update your one imageview with the images. 
Caching views is rarely what you want.

Comment: Then the OP would have 20 references to the same imageview, which is not what he intends, for sure, but different from "empty", which he claims.

Comment: I have to insert the imageview because I have to cache them. This code is only an example

Comment: @Anna565 you have to show where you access the array because there's not enough context to determine why you can't see the contents